# Python speed optimization when downloading 1000+ zip files from URL

Tags: python, apache-spark, url, download, zip

I am trying to download zip files containing a csv file.

On one hand I have more than 3000 URL therefore 3000 files. The code used took between 1 to 2 hours. The total size of the zip files is 40GB. Unzipped 230GB.

On the other hand there is also another set of URLs on the 100Ks. Looking at how long it took to process the previous number of URLs, is there something I can do to improve this code?
Should I make it all in one function?

I have the possibility to run this on a Spark cluster.

```
#URLs in a list called links
#Filepaths are a list from ls on the folder of the raw zip files

def download_zip_files(x,base_url,filepath):
  r = requests.get(x)
  status_code = r.status_code
  filepath = str(x.replace(base_url,filepath))
  with open(filepath, "wb") as file:
    file.write(r.content)

def extract_zip_files(x,basepath,exportpath):
  path = str(basepath+x[1])
  with zipfile.ZipFile(path, "r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(exportpath)

list(map(lambda x: download_zip_files(x,base_url,filepath), links))
list(map(lambda x: extract_zip_files(x,basepath,exportpath), raw_zip_filepaths))
```

Comment: First off, what kind of internet connection is at your availability? For a 50k connection that would already be the max. just asking in case thats already the limit

Comment: @FloLie I usually have up to 5 MB.

Comment: Well 40GB by 5MB/s does amount to more than 2 hours, therefore your connection seems to be the limiting factor as of now or am i missing something?

Comment: Other than that, you should look at parallelization using multi_processing library

Comment: And you should also consider using ther requests.get(stream=True) option, because as you do it, you load the whole zip files to memory, which can lead to out of memory issues

Comment: I completely ignored my internet speed. I will look into parallelization, is that related with the Spark cluster?

Comment: No thats a rather basic concept. Either you donwload and process the files consecutively or multiple in parallel. How much that helps to speed up the task, depends on the kind of task. A CPU bound task such as culculations does improve (almost) proportional with the number of cores. IO bound tasks may depend on other potential bottlnecks. such as network throughput, disk read/write etc

Answer (score 2):

What you need is multithreading, A quick google definition is as follows:

> Multithreading is a CPU (central processing unit) feature that allows two or more instruction threads to execute independently while sharing the same processor resources. A thread is a self-contained sequence of instructions that can execute in parallel with other threads that are part of the same root process.

Most of the time the programs we write are executed in a single-threaded manner (same as yours) each instruction in the program executes in a sequence, which is slow if we have a case like yours, to run a program parallelly through multiple threads see the following example.

**Single thread**

[image]

**Multi-thread approach**

[image]
Please consider the output of both single-threaded and multi-threaded examples.
In a multi-threaded example, the program is executing in parallel through threads. In simple words, the print_words() function executes two times parallelly(at the same time) with different parameters.

Let's come to your example:
You can divide your URL list into multiple URL lists and give each thread a list of URLs, see the following example which is just a sudo code you should implement it by yourself.

```
  import threading
  
  # Please divide the following list using any function I'm giving a simple example right now, so I'm not doing this.
  url_list=['url1','url2','url3','url4'] 
  # Following lists are divided into two lists.
  url_list_1=['url1','url2']
  url_list_2=['url3','url4']
  
  def download_zip_files(x,base_url,filepath):
    r = requests.get(x)
    status_code = r.status_code
    filepath = str(x.replace(base_url,filepath))
    with open(filepath, "wb") as file:
    file.write(r.content)
  
  def start_loop_download_zip(links):     
    list(map(lambda x: download_zip_files(x,base_url,filepath), links))
  

  t1 = threading.Thread(target=start_loop_download_zip,args=(url_list_1,))
  t2 = threading.Thread(target=start_loop_download_zip,args=(url_list_2,))
  # starting thread 1
  t1.start()
  # starting thread 2
  t2.start()
  # wait until thread 1 is completely executed
  t1.join()
  # wait until thread 2 is completely executed
  t2.join()
```

This approach will significantly reduce your processing time.

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for. I had no idea about the Threading option. Thank you.

Comment: You can also learn about multi-processing which also helps you with other use cases in which your function does lots of manipulation. 
Please upvote and accept the answer if it helps you. Thank you!